# Suppose that $f : X \to Y$ is a one-to-one function and $A, B\subset X$ with $f(A) = f(B)$. Then $A = B$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a one-to-one function and $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$ such that $f(A) = f(B)$. Then $A = B$.

I either have to prove if this is true or give a counter example if this is false... suggestions on where to start would be helpful!

Comment: Start by proving it, remember what it means to be one-to-one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a\in A$ then $f(a)\in f(A)=f(B)$. so $f(a)=f(b)$ for some $b\in B$. now "$f$ is one-to-one" implies $a=b$; so $a\in B$. we proved $A\subset B$. the  converse is similar.